# How to send a whatsapp message from my web application ASP.NET?

Tags: html, asp.net, web, whatsapp

I am working on an ASP.NET web application and I want to send a WhatsApp message from it by pressing on a share button to share a specific link, anyone has any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is using an anchor

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=My Text">WhatsApp</a>
```

Or programatically with some provider

https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-a-whatsapp-message-with-c-in-30-seconds